# Controlling a program that was automatically started using pipes

Tags: linux, centos, named-pipes

I have a program that needs to be automatically started when I boot a CentOS server.

After the program has been started, I want to be able to SSH into the server and control this program (read its output and send it input).

I have been trying to use Named Pipes for this purpose, but I've not been able to work out how to do so.

How can I accomplish this type of control?

Comment: Minecraft? Use something like mcrcon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you start the process inside `screen` and then connect to the screen session after boot?

I usually do something like this from within `rc.local` on Ubuntu. I use `at` to launch it so if the launched process doesn't exit cleanly, it doesn't terminate the execution of `rc.local`:

```
echo '/usr/bin/screen -dmS my_proc /root/someprocess' | at now
```

Then `ssh` in later and issue `screen -x my_proc`
Just be sure you don't kill the screen session (detach from `screen`, don't exit)